# Navigating Menu control to some .aspx page

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, menu, menuitem

How can i navigate to some .aspx page from Menu control's menu items.

Thanks!

Comment: You could bind its data source to a site map, ala this example: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/aspnets-menu-control-offers-another-site-map-navigation-option/479

Comment: I have a Menu control which has 2-3 menu items in it. Clicking on one of them should open the desired .aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

On menu item clicke vent.

me.navigate("page.aspx")

Unless I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **NavigateUrl** property of the MenuItem:

```
 <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Root" Value="Root">
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com" Text="Child 1" 
                        Value="Child 1"></asp:MenuItem>
                </asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
```